# How to change value of variable from different python file referenced different class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, scope

I have a main python file and a class in a different python file. I have tried to change a variable in the python file from the class. However, I don't know how to do this outside of the `__init__` function.

The class:

```
class Matrices:
    currentMenuItem = 0
    dataForMatrix = {}

    def __init__(self, memory, matricesFrame, tempBoolsControl, otherControls):
        self.memory = memory
        self.matricesFrame = matricesFrame
        self.tempBoolsControl = tempBoolsControl
        self.otherControls = otherControls

    def createNewMatrix(self):
        self.otherControls["right"] = False
```

The main file:

```
from Matrices import Matrices

otherControls = {"right": True, "left": True}

Matrices(memory, matricesFrame, tempBoolsControl, otherControls).createNewMatrix()
```

This is meant to change the `otherControls` variable in the main file, but it only changes it locally. I can't access the original `otherControls` variable outside of the `__init__` function. Can anyone help?

Comment: local variable `othercontrols` != class attribute `self.othercontrols`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save the Matrices object to a variable, e.g.

`mat = Matrices(memory, matricesFrame, tempBoolsControl, otherControls).createNewMatrix()`

you can access the `otherControls` attribute like this:

```
mat.otherControls = {'right':True, 'left':False}
# or if you want only one of the keys
mat.otherControls['right'] = False
```